# TypeError: todos.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to sent data todos from my-house to list-house but I cannot read data in class list-house
but I can show data todos in html i dont understand .................................................................................................................................................................................
[image]

**Myhouse**

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import { firestore } from "../../firebase/firebase.utils";
import Listhouse from "../list-house/list-house.component.jsx";
class Myhouse extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      house_id: [],
      todos: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firestore
      .collection("house")
      .where("email", "==", this.props.currentUser.email)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          this.setState({
            house_id: doc.id,
            todos: doc.data(),
          });
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container
        maxWidth="xl"
        style={{ paddingTop: "2%", paddingBottom: "2%" }}
      >
        <Listhouse  todos={todos} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Myhouse);
```

**Listhouse**

```js
import React from "react";
import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Cardhouse from "../card-house/card-house.component.jsx";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

class Listhouse extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: this.props.todos,
    };
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.todos !== this.state.todos) {
      //Perform some operation
      this.setState({ todos: nextProps.todos });
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    let currentPage = 1;
    const todosPerPage = 6;
    // Logic for displaying todos
    const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = todos.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);



    const handleClick = (event, value) => {
      currentPage = Number(value);
    };
    // Logic for displaying page numbers
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(todos.length / todosPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="h5">
            {"บ้านของฉัน"}
            {todos.length} รายการ
          </Typography>
          {todos.length > 0 ? (
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">
              หน้า: {currentPage} / {pageNumbers.length}
            </Typography>
          ) : (
            <Grid
              container
              direction="row"
              justify="center"
              alignItems="center"
              style={{ paddingTop: "25%" }}
            >
              <Typography variant="h5">ไม่พบรายการที่ค้นหา</Typography>
            </Grid>
          )}
          <Cardhouse currentTodos={currentTodos} />
          <Pagination
            count={pageNumbers.length}
            page={currentPage}
            size="large"
            id={currentPage}
            onChange={handleClick}
            showFirstButton={todos.length > 0}
            showLastButton={todos.length > 0}
            style={{ paddingTop: "2%" }}
            hideNextButton={todos.length === 0}
            hidePrevButton={todos.length === 0}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default Listhouse;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are setting todos state within forEach and hence the todos will not be an array but an object on which slick isn't defined

You need to write it like

```js
.then((querySnapshot) => {
  var houseId = [];
  var todos  [];

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       houseId.push(doc.id);
       todos.push(doc.data());
       console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
   this.setState({
      house_id: houseId,
      todos,
    });
});
```

P.S. Also you need not save props into state in `Lighthouse` component, you can directly use `todos` from props. The idea here is that is state is directly derivable from props, you can directly use props